# Hiding last date of previous employment

Tags: new-job, india, notice-period

I live in India.My new employer expects me to join them after 60 days. My notice period with old employer is 90 days. However, I gave my resignation 80 days before and I have just 10 days more to serve and can join the new place immediately without having to wait 60 days. My new employer doesn't know this fact. But they have asked me to reduce the notice period to the maximum extent possible.

I want to go on a study break for these 60 days instead of joining the new place. If I tell the new employer that I am already relieved from the previous employer, they would expect me to join immediately.

I have 2 options.

Option 1 
Sit and study, then join after 60 days. They will ask me for my relieving letter and come to know that I was free since the past 60 days. I' ll cover up saying that I had some personal issues and had to go overseas.

Option 2
Tell them truthfully that I have no notice period to serve, however, I will tell them that I need to go overseas due to personal issues and that it is long-planned and tickets are already booked. I fear that the new employer will force me to join earlier.

What should I do?

Comment: I think you should reword your question, you're asking us "Should I tell this lie, or this other lie?"  Unless you do actually have travel plans, in which case this question is a moot point.

Answer (score 6):

Lies will usually be found out, and then you are in trouble. The best thing to do is tell them that you only have to serve one more week, but that you wish to go on your studies for 60 days. Then you can negotiate. Be strong while you negotiate. You know they can live with you joining 60 days later, because that's what they expect to happen. One possible result is that you study for 30 days, join, and after half a year take 30 days off.

Lying about it and being found out, that will be very bad for you.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is flat out awful - they will surely be able to work out from your relieving letter that you will have known at this point in time that the 60 days wasn't true and an unforseen "personal issue" will be seen as the weak lie that it is. Given they are already asking you to try and start as soon as you can you'll not only look deceitful but uncooperative as well.

Option 2 is *better* but unless you really do have a trip booked then I think you're just asking to get caught out on this. You're going to have to either a) refuse to answer any questions about your trip once you start (and look aloof) or b) fabricate a believeable narrative for the trip and stick to it for an extended period of time. Also if there were really a "long-planned" and "already booked" trip then they might wonder why you never mentioned it earlier in the dialog.

If you are really set on having a study break would you be open to one that was shorter than the full 60 days? that would open the door to a third option - tell them the truth about your finish date at your old employer and you can give them this in terms of it being Good News(TM), you are going to be available much sooner than they thought. However you tell them that you need say 20 days to sort out some personal matters/decompress/whatever before you start "so you can focus properly on starting with the new company" (or similar). Hopefully they will be sufficiently pleased that you will be starting 30 days sooner than they there initially expecting that they won't make an issue of the 20 days but it still gives you some wiggle room if you become concerned that they are getting cold feet regarding taking you on.